# As variáveis escopadas são deletadas mesmo em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, escopo-de-variáveis

No JavaScript, sempre que o bloco de um escopo de variáveis executa, todas suas variáveis são deletadas (como dizem em torno do site)...

```
(function() {
    var a = false;
})()
```

Mas então por que quando chamo o `setTimeout` para alertar o valor de uma variável ainda reconhece? Ou seja, as variáveis não são deletadas?

```
(function() {
    var a = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(a)
    }, 1000);
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `Javascript` existem dois tipos de escopo, que são global e local.

**Escopo global** é quando você define uma variável fora do bloco de código de uma função, assim a variável ficando acessível para todo o código.

**Por exemplo:**

```
var variavelGlobal = 10;

function funcOne() {
   alert(variavelGlobal);
}

function funcTwo() {
   alert(variavelGlobal + 10);
}

funcOne();
funcTwo();
```

**Escopo local** é quando se define uma variável dentro de uma função, assim ela ficando acessível somente dentro dessa função.

**Por exemplo:**

```
function funcOne() {

   var variavelLocal = 10;

   alert(variavelLocal);
}

function funcTwo() {
   alert(variavelLocal + 10);//Um erro será lançado.
}

funcOne();
funcTwo();
```

**Observação:** Sempre que se for criar variáveis no Javascript, leve em consideração a utilização da palavra reservada `var`, pois sem sua utilização dentro do escopo de uma função, as variáveis dentro dela ser tornaram globais.

**Por exemplo:**

```
function funcOne() {

   variavelLocal = 10;//Sem a palavra reservada 'var'.

   alert(variavelLocal);
}

function funcTwo() {
   alert(variavelLocal + 10);//Não será lançado um erro, pois 'variavelLocal' é global.
}

funcOne();
funcTwo();
```

Respondendo sua pergunta, as variáveis definidas dentro do escopo de uma função, somente são deixam de existir fora do escopa local, que é fora da função, no escopo global, assim elas não ficaram acessiveis, porém elas sempre existiram dentro do escopo da função onde elas foram definidas. Quando essa função é executada e quando essa função termina sua execução elas são deletadas até o `setTimeout` acabar.

Comment: Sim, eu entendo que elas são deletadas quando a função executa, porém eu observei uma falha como notada na questão quando eu chamo `setTimeout`.

Comment: O setTimeout está dentro da função onde a variável 'a' foi criada, então a variável 'a' ainda continuará a existi, pois o setTimeout pertence ao seu bloco de execução.

Comment: Mas o bloco da função já vai ter executado antes de o `setTimeout` chamar a função de callback. Ou há chances de que as variáveis da função estejam sendo memorizadas para o setTimeout...

Comment: Não, só é terminado quando o setTimeout acaba sua execução.

Comment: Não penso muito assim porque o `setTimeout` é nativo. Mas parece ser a única ideia ideia, então...

Comment: @KlaiderKlai as variáveis não são "deletadas" mas sim não existentes caso sejam declaradas num escopo interno. Quando há uma função asyncrona como o setTimeout activa (ie à espera de ser executada) o bloco é mantido em memória.